# How to store data of edited row of mat table in a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have mat table which contains 3 columns: Key,Value and edit icon. 
When i click on edit icon then value part is editable. Now after clicking update button i want to store all edited cell's value in variables, so that i can pass it to my backend to update the data in database. How can i achieve that?
Below is my code:

here is my stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifrzkl-tg4eha?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

> approval.componenet.html

```
<div>
    <button mat-stroked-button class="b1" (click)="update()" formtarget="_blank">Update</button>
    <h5>Request Details</h5>
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="key">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="item-name"> {{element.key}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="value" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > 
              <span *ngIf="!element.editable; else editPlace">
              {{element.value}} 
              </span>
              <ng-template #editPlace>
                <input [(ngModel)]="element.value" (keyup.enter)="element.editable = false">
              </ng-template>
            </td>
          </ng-container>


          <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Actions </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Click to Edit" (click)="edit(element)" class="iconbutton" color="primary">
                  <mat-icon aria-label="Edit">edit</mat-icon>
                </button>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>


        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

> approval.component.ts

```
edit(e: any) {
    e.editable = !e.editable;
  }

  update()
  {
    const usr=this.value;
    console.log(usr);
  }
```

[image: This is my mat table]

Answer (score 1):

You need make some changes in your code

**In HTML change**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="element.value" (keyup.enter)="element.editable = false">
```

to

```
<input [(ngModel)]="element.value" (keyup.enter)="element.editable = false" (change)="changeValue(element.value)" >
```

**And in TS:**

Add this function:

```
  changeValue(event: any){
       this.element = event;
  }
```

The thing you are doing wrong is you are declaring variable element but you are not assigning any value to it.

Here is the stackblitz code where i had made some changes

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifrzkl-gfzcug

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You've already got two-way binding using `[(ngModel)]` on `element.value` so each change to the input should be mirrored in the `element` object in your component typescript... So what's the issue here?

Edit: instead of logging `this.value`, log `this.dataSource`.

Comment: i am consoling const usr=this.element;
    console.log(usr); but getting undefined

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifrzkl-tg4eha?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: As I said, your `dataSource` automatically gets the updated values when you click the "Update" button -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifrzkl-y7chjh

Comment: can you please come on chat?